# Queue connection

Tags: java, jms

```
            environment.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,QUEUE_CONTEXT);
            System.out.println("QUEUE_URL -> " + QUEUE_URL);
            environment.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,QUEUE_URL);
            try{
            ctx = new InitialDirContext(environment);
            String MYCF_LOOKUP_NAME = QUEUE_CONTEXT_FACTORY;
            connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup(MYCF_LOOKUP_NAME);
            connection = ((MQQueueConnectionFactory) connectionFactory)
                                        .createQueueConnection();
```

I dont know whther it correct or not.. It gives me connectivity issue
n the first program it asks for queue manager name but in the second program it doesn't require Queue Manager name. I need to replace the First program code with the second program.. Can anyone help me on this ..??

Comment: It's absolutely unclear what you are trying to ask. You've also posted  seemingly irrelevant code. Please cut it down to what really causes the problem.

Comment: Check http://sscce.org to get an example of what you should be posting. And be more specific in your question.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis hi.. actually i just posted the code for my friend to get it. My actual problem is.. I am not able to connect to the MQ 7. I need to connect it without the queue name. In the below comment i will add the code :

Comment: Hashtable environment = new java.util.Hashtable();                 
            environment.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,QUEUE_URL);
            environment.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,QUEUE_CONTEXT);

InitialDirContext ctx = null;
            ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = null;
            Connection connection = null;
            Queue queuess;

Comment: ctx = new InitialDirContext(environment);
            String MYCF_LOOKUP_NAME = QUEUE_CONTEXT_FACTORY;
            connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory)                                            ctx.lookup(MYCF_LOOKUP_NAME);
            
            queuess = (Queue)ctx.lookup("con=");//What should i give here.. just the Queue_name or con=Queue_name

Kindly help me

Comment: @SJuan76 this is the exception i get 

"javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: con=Queue_name"

Answer (score 0):

You're using JNDI here - JNDI is a store of Java Obects. For JMS this will be ConnectionFactorys and Destinations (Queues or Topics).

So you need to put into JNDI an Connection Factory as the code suggets you already have and also a Queue.

Would suggest if this is not clear why you need to do this I suggest searching for a JNDI tuturial and also a JMS one - to get the very basic background.

Comment: sorry this is the correct [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19806498/failed-to-create-queue-manager-error-jmsexception-mqjms2005)

Comment: Are you able to find it?